# Showing there exists an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $\text{Row}(A) = U$ and $\text{Col}(A) = V$ where $U$ and $V$ are subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $F$ be a field. Let $U$ be a subspace of $F^n$ and let $V$ be a subspace of $F^m$. Suppose that $\dim U = \dim V$. Then there exists an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in $F$ such that $\operatorname{Row}(A) = U$ and $\operatorname{Col}(A) = V$.

This is what I have tried, but some calculations have shown that this is wrong.

Suppose $\dim U = \dim V = k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathcal{A} = \{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_k\}\subseteq F^n$ be a basis for $U$ and let $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k\}\subseteq F^m$ be a basis for $V$. Let $P \in M_{m \times k}(F)$ be the matrix with columns $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ and let $Q\in M_{k\times n}(F)$ be the matrix with rows $u_1, \ldots, u_k$. Clearly, $\operatorname{Row}(Q) = U$ and $\operatorname{Col}(P) = V$. I first thought that
$$
A = PQ \in M_{m\times n}(F)
$$
but after trying some examples I have found that this $A$ does not do the job.

Am I on the right track, or is there a better construction of $A$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Such an $A$ would be a linear transformation from $F^n$ to $F^m$. What would its image and kernel be?

Comment: If $A$ is the linear transformation $L: F^n \to F^m$ then $\operatorname{Image}(L) = V$ since $\operatorname{Col}(A) = V$, right?

Comment: @user226744 There is no "_the_ linear transformation". Any $m\times n$ matrix is such a transformation, and any such transformation is a matrix. However, you want this one to have a specific column space and a specific row space, and there are theorems for connecting the collumn space to the kernel, and the row space to the image.